# RequireJS loads resources I don't want to

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS in my app, but don't quite well understand all aspects of it's work.

I have `main.js` file, where dependencies are described. I have `Backbone.Router` component up and running, which triggers different `application` classes (class which is responsible to create main view). Some code you can see [here](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/candidate/tree/master/src/Candidate.Nancy.Selfhosted/Client/scripts).

What I can see with requireJS: even if some view has not been yet 'required' (mean explicitly call to require('./subviews/view)), it's still loaded and inside it loads all templates (I use requireJS text plugin). If I'm adding new application but it's subviews are not ready, but I never used the application - nonexisting subviews are still loaded and I'm getting 404 errors.

Not sure I explained everything clearly, but hope you got point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using the [CommonJS sugared form of define()](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar). Note that this is just a convenience for wrapping Node/CommonJS code, but AMD modules do not operate like Node modules.

An AMD loader will scan for require('') calls in the factory function of the module, and make sure to load all the modules. Otherwise, synchronous access to the that module, by doing a `require('./apps/DashboardApp');`, would fail in the browser, since file IO is by default async network IO.

If you want to delay loading of some scripts, then you need to use the callback-form of require:

```
require(['./apps/DashboardApp'], function (DashboardApp) {
});
```

but this call is an async call, so you would have to adjust your module's public API accordingly.

So basically, if you want to do on-demand loading of a dependency, the callback form of require is needed, given the async nature of file IO in the browser.

Comment: Great answer, I'll try it out. I liked that form of define, having just a function as argument.

Comment: And you said - "you would have to adjust your module's public API accordingly" - could you please give me any hints on that, what exactly have to be changed?

Comment: it just means that if your module's exposed functions that are used by other modules expected a synchronous return value based on something from DashboardApp, you would need to adjust your module's API to accept a callback that would be called once DashboardApp loads.

Answer (score 1):

Because RequireJS loads all required dependencies. By taking quick look at your code I see that you load routing module and routing has:

```
var ViewManager = require('ViewManager');
```

That means it will load ViewManager, dependecies that are specified by ViewManager and other dependencies that those modules need. Essentially when you include require(...), it's the same as specifying dependency. This will be transformed by RequireJS into

`define(['ViewManager'], ...)`

Comment: If you take a look inside ViewManager, this is simple object, with no dependencies. What I can see, is that dependency is not required, but requireJS still wan't to load it.

Comment: Yes, but there are other calls to require. Although their are not needed initially as James described because of sugared version of define() AMD loader will parse out the require('') calls by using Function.prototype.toString() and will load all dependencies.